# CSS image alignment difference between firefox and chrome

Tags: css, image, alignment, vertical-alignment

I can't get my images to align correctly between all browsers:

[image]

I'm wondering if it's a border issue?

**Question**:  would the best way to resolve this be to create a media query? Right now I sort of try to find a good middle ground, but when viewed on a safari mobile app, those few pixels make a big difference. Or is there a better way to contain the image between the `.mnhouse, .mnsenate, .ushouse, .ussenate1, .ussenate2` divs?

Here is my relevant HTML:

```
<div id="officials">                 
            <div class='mnhouse'>                       
                    <div class="membersublist">
                         <div class="memberLink"><span id="mnhouselink">Show District <i class="fa fa-external-link-square"></i></span></div>       
                        <div id='housemember' class='lcc_gis_member'></div>
                        <div id='housedistrict' class='lcc_gis_memberdistrict'></div>
                    </div>
                    <img id='housephoto' class='mnhouse_img' src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs=" width="0" height="0" alt=""/>

            </div>
            <div class='mnsenate'>                      
                    <div class="membersublist">
                        <div class="memberLink"><span id="mnsenlink">Show District <i class="fa fa-external-link-square"></i></span></div>
                        <div id='senatemember' class='lcc_gis_member'></div>
                        <div id='senatedistrict' class='lcc_gis_memberdistrict'></div>
                    </div>
                    <img id='senatephoto' class='mnsenate_img' src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs=" width="0" height="0" alt=""/>                   
            </div>
</div>
```

And here is my relevant CSS:

```
#officials img {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 87px;
    max-width: 65%;
    position: relative;
    top: -56px;
    border:none;
}

.membersublist{
    margin-top:15px;
}
.mnhouse, .mnsenate, .ushouse, .ussenate1, .ussenate2 {
    height:87px;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    border-top: 1px solid #a7a5a6;
    border-right: 1px solid #a7a5a6;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #a7a5a6;
    border-left: 3px solid #a7a5a6;
}
```

Here is the **[demo](http://www.gis.leg.mn/iMaps/districts/)**, in case I miss any relevant code (you need to select a point on the map to open the results).

Comment: The main issue here is that you put the image below the text and try fix it with `top: -56px`, which will not work as the font renders different and will effect its element's height, hence the different render result. What you need to do is to move the image into a left column and the text into a right, then this will be no issue anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your use of negative relative positioning to try to line it up.

```
#officials img {
    ...
    position: relative;
    top: -56px;
    ...
}
```

Basically you are positioning it relative to the offset created be the text, which can never be counted upon to be 100% consistent across browsers.

Instead, consider adding positioning to `.mnhouse` wrapper, and then using absolute positioning to position the images.

```
.mnhouse {
    position: relative;
}

#officials img {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 87px;
    max-width: 65%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    border:none;
}
```